# how to add rows for one attribute in a table

Tags: php, mysql

on mysql how can i add rows to only one attribute in a table? or how can i break line as the data is displayed?
is it possible to do this without adding a new table?

table:

```
case title people vs john
docket number 11235
nature appeal
action taken july 11 received case folder. july 12 create pleading. july 14 file pleading ...
status
```

how to display the table like this:

```
`case title people vs john
docket number 11235
nature appeal
action taken july 11 received case folder
         july 12 create pleading
         july 14 file pleading
status awaiting further notice
```

note that the action taken has many iterations that is why i was hoping to add a new row or break line as it is displayed

for reference:
[sample of what is currently happening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xA2j.png)

Comment: It's best if questions have some semblance of sense about them.

Answer (score 0):

If the `action taken` is a flat strig you can use an update

```
  update my_table 
  set `action taken` = concat( `action taken` , ' ' , 'july 14 file pleading')
  where `case title` = 'people vs john'
  and `docket number` =  11235;
```

but if you need a normalized solution you should create a table for action taken related to you main table

my_master_table

```
id 
case title
docket number
nature
status
```

my_action_taken_table 
    id
    master_id
    action_taken

and the use insert for adding a new action taked and join for selecting